# which machine learning technique should be used for message classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, bayesian

I have a dataset having customer message and final category one of example is following-

```
key   message                                                  final category
1     i want customer care no i want to talk with ur team       other
2     hi I 9986443603cjhh had qkuiv1uhqllljqvocally q illgi vq  noclass
3     hai points not coming                                     checking
```

like. The dataset is huge file with at least 20 final category type. Please suggest appropriate method to classify the data with a message which will be its final category. I am thinking of making feature_vector with message word and feed it into Bayesian would it be great? Or I have to use other technique.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider word-embedding.
You can download from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) the embbedings (in this link- `Glove`, you can alternatively use `word2vec`).

The idea is that similar words will have similar vectors.
After you convert each word in your message to a vector you can average all the vectors (or, average using `TF-IDF` for better results) to get the vector-representation of your message. 
Of course, words like qkuiv1uhqllljqvocally will not appear in the vocabulary. 
To check your results, you can cluster(using 20-means clustering, if you have 20 classes) all your vectors to see that similar messages cluster to the same group.